# Wrap child scss file with parent class

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to add a parent class to all rules in a child scss file. By interpreting the child file as if it was already compiled?

Currently, I tried to wrap an `@import` with a parent class but it doesn't work as expected.

#### parent.scss

```
.parent{
   @import 'child';
}
```

#### child.scss

```
.child{
   .dark &{
      color: blue;
   }
}
```

#### Actual output

```css
.dark .parent .child {
  color: blue; 
}
```

#### Expected output

```css
.parent .dark .child {
  color: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution using [meta.load-css() mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#load-css)

### child.scss

```scss
.child{
   .dark &{
      color: blue;
   }
}
```

### parent.scss

```scss
@use "sass:meta";
.parent {
    @include meta.load-css("child");
}
```

here is a working example: https://github.com/zeckaissue/Wrap-child-scss-file-with-parent-class